# Reflect on annotation class from within scala macro annotation?

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations, scala-macros

Is there a way to access the constructor declaration of a macro annotation from within the macro implementation by reflection? For example, when I define this macro annotation:

```scala
class Component(x: String, y: Int = 0) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro ComponentMacro.impl
}
```

is it possible to reflect on the `Component` from within the macro implementation? When I use something like:

```scala
class ComponentMacro(val c: whitebox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def impl(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*) = {
    /* ... */
    val t = typeOf[Component] // throws exception
  }
}
```

the compiler throws an error during macro expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `c.prefix.tree`, as in the example below:

```
class ComponentMacro(val c:  scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def impl(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    val annottation = c.prefix.tree
    annottation match {
      case q""" new $className(..$params) """ => println(s"className=$className, x=$params")
    }
    c.Expr(q""" case class Test() """)
  }
}
```

For this annotated class:

```
@Component("FooBar", 5)
case class Test()
```

It will output:

```
Warning:scalac: className=Component, x=List("FooBar", 5)
```

Comment: Tanks for the reply; however, my original question was not how to access the actual annotation value (-> your example), but to reflect on the **declaration** of the annotation class (e.g. what are the names and types of the constructor arguments).

Comment: Oh, sorry to have misunderstood your question. I don't know how to do what you want, but I am curious to know the answer. Maybe you could add the details of the exception which is thrown by the compiler?